# what are the following terms used in filter mapping?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

what is request,forward and include used for?

Answer (score 2):

This is whether to invoke the filter when forward or include is used.

For example, if you have `request.getRequestDispatcher("/bar.jsp").forward(req, resp)`, the filter will be invoked before the forwarded resource is processed.